# Running a game over VNC is appearing as a black blank screen

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, remote-desktop, vnc

I am running a Mac 10.7 and want to remote into my PC (running Windows 7 Ultimate) downstairs which is running Star Wars Old Republic game. I tried to install RDC and now VNC. VNC seems to work fine I got it setup, I can control my desk through my Mac.

However when I run Star War Old Republic game, all I get is a black blank screen. I am not sure why but this doesn't seem to work. But I tried to play World of Warcraft this seems to work perfectly fine!

I read on forums people have no problem running Star Wars game on VNC, but I have had no luck. I heard it maybe something to do with DirectX, but I dont know anything about that.

I also tried to forward the port to the PC again no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are different techniques used for hardware access in accelerated graphics, and some of them bypass the APIs that a remote desktop solution uses to capture the graphics. All I can suggest here is try different programs, as suggested by others below.

Comment: Ok.  I don't get it.  You've been back after I answered the question.  Did TurboVNC work for you?  Is there a reason why you don't want to try it?  Is there a reason why you don't want to try any other version of VNC?  Is there a reason why you'd abandon the question?

Answer (score 2):

The particular flavor of VNC makes a big difference... not only in the server you install on the Windows box, but the client you use on your Mac.

For example, [TurboVNC](http://www.virtualgl.org/About/TigerVNC) is made specifically for gaming across VNC.  You can download both a Windows server install and a Mac client install [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/TurboVNC/).  You'd just examine the version 1.1 listing... the .dmg image would be for the Mac.

Otherwise, it's all about the display delay times, virtual video drivers, etc.  So, I'd start there.

Just remember, with VNC you are always going to have some measure of delay, and no sound.

You'd be able to get sound with RDP, but even that, with two computers sitting next to each other cabled to the same switch or router, you can end up with sound issues.  I'm curious as to why the [Mac RDP client](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) didn't work?